# Selenium IDE fails to open a test suite (no file open dialog)

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am not able to access the file open dialog in Selenium IDE 2.9.1 (Firefox 48.0, Win 10). File > Open results in this error message:

```
There was an unexpected error. Msg: NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH: Component returned failure code: 0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH) [nsILocalFile.initWithPath]
Url: chrome://selenium-ide/content/file-utils.js, line: 32
FileUtils.getFile@chrome://selenium-ide/content/file-utils.js:32:5
showFilePicker@chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js:102:31
Application.prototype.loadTestCaseWithNewSuite@chrome://selenium-ide/content/application.js:259:20
Editor.prototype.loadRecentTestCase@chrome://selenium-ide/content/editor.js:489:5
Editor.controller.doCommand@chrome://selenium-ide/content/editor.js:366:9
goDoCommand@chrome://global/content/globalOverlay.js:100:7
oncommand@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-ide.xul:1:1
```

File > Open Test Suite results in a shorter error:

```
error loading test suite: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH) [nsILocalFile.initWithPath]"  nsresult: "0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://selenium-ide/content/file-utils.js :: FileUtils.getFile :: line 32"  data: no]
```

Does anyone have a clue what's wrong here?

Comment: Where is the file saved and have you had issues opening files from there before? After looking around a bit I've found some people who have had a same issue when the file in question is being opened from a networked location

Comment: It is a html-TestSuite-File on my local hard disk. But the problem occurs before I am able to open any path: The file open dialog does not appear at all - only the error boxes pasted above.

Comment: In that case, In a new Firefox Tab type in about:config, and once in there search for:
extensions.selenium-ide.testCaseDirectory
and
extensions.selenium-ide.testSuiteDirectory
Check the file path there and make sure it is a valid one. They control the default location you start at when opening files, could be an issue with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the solution. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it. The cause of the problem was that my Firefox Profile was copied from Linux some time ago - and the Linux paths were still saved there without my knowledge. It would have helped a lot if the error message contained the path Selenium was trying to open (and the about:config-Key it came from).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a new Firefox Tab type in about:config, and once in there search for: extensions.selenium-‌​ide.testCaseDirectory and extensions.selenium-‌​ide.testSuiteDirector‌​y Check the file path there and make sure it is a valid one. They control the default location you start at when opening files, could be an issue with that.